# Difficulties understanding java.lang.Math output

Tags: java, algorithm, math, floating-point, int

I'm having some difficulty understanding why the output differs. Hopefully, someone can explain what's going on here.

The below code calculates the volume and surface area as expected (33.5103 and 50.2655, respectively) when I enter `2`, but if I change the equation for Volume from `(4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 3);` to `(4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 3);`, the output is 25.1327

Why is the output different when I change **4.0** to **4**?

```
import java.lang.Math;  // Import the Math class.
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class.
import java.text.DecimalFormat; // Import the DecimalFormat class.

class Main {

  public static double calcVolume(double r) {
    // Return Volume.
    return (4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 3);
  }

  public static double calcSurfaceArea(double r) {
    // Return the Surface Area.
    return 4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(r, 2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Prompt user for the radius.
    Scanner radius_in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the radius to calculate volume and surface area: "); 

    Double radius = radius_in.nextDouble();

    Double volume = calcVolume(radius);
    Double surfaceArea = calcSurfaceArea(radius);

    // Set up decimalformat object for outputting to 4 decimal places.
    DecimalFormat DF = new DecimalFormat("0.####");

    System.out.println("Volume is: " + DF.format(volume));
    System.out.println("Surface Area is: " + DF.format(surfaceArea));

  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not a duplicate, but read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0 anyway.

Comment: `4.0 / 3` is `1.33...`; `4 / 3` is `1`. The division will be integral unless at least one argument is floating.

Comment: Because of 4/3 returns 1, whereas 4.0/3 returns 1.333

Comment: Revise the title of this Question to summarize more specifically your particular technical issue. How is your question distinct from all the other java.lang.Math questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because with `4.0 / 3` you're getting a floating point precision, whereas `4 / 3` is considered as int. This means, that whatever is evaluated as `4 / 3`, the decimal part is cut off:

```
4.0 / 3 => 1.(3)
4 / 3 => (int) (1.(3)) => 1
```

Comment: Even though I'm setting it as a Double? I'm pretty new to Java, so my ignorance is showing, I'm sure.

Comment: The return type of the method doesn't matter. The equation is being resolved, then it's converted to `double` (at return statement) as needed.

Comment: Ah. So because both values supplied are integers, Java is performing integer division and converting that to a double?

Comment: To be more precise the part between braces is fed with integers so it's resolved as integer.